# O que significa o sinal de arroba "@" no C#?

Tags: c#, string

Tenho a seguinte *string* `@"\\servidor01\arquivos"`. Qual a função do `@` na frente da *string*?

Answer (score 62, accepted):

Significa uma *string* literal, ou uma *string* crua, sem considerar os caracteres de escape.

O caractere `\` atua como escape para inserir [caracteres especiais na *string*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb546106.aspx), e como é um endereço de rede, você realmente quer que esse caractere seja considerado.

Caso você não utilize o `@`, você teria que duplicar a barra invertida dessa maneira:

```
string a = "\\\\servidor01\\arquivos";
```

Segue alguns outros exemplos com o conteúdo que a variável irá apresentar.

```
string a = "hello, world";                // hello, world
string b = @"hello, world";               // hello, world
string c = "hello \t world";              // hello     world
string d = @"hello \t world";             // hello \t world
string e = "Joe said \"Hello\" to me";    // Joe said "Hello" to me
string f = @"Joe said ""Hello"" to me";   // Joe said "Hello" to me
string g = "\\\\server\\share\\file.txt"; // \\server\share\file.txt
string h = @"\\server\share\file.txt";    // \\server\share\file.txt
string i = "one\r\ntwo\r\nthree";
string j = @"one
two
three";
```

Referência: [Microsoft Docs](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/tokens/verbatim)

Comment: O termo usado para strings começadas com @ é verbatim, literal já é qualquer string que está direto no código delimitada por aspas duplas, seja ela uma string regular ou verbatim, e eu não diria que ela não considera caracteres de escape, na verdade nela o único caractere de escape que existe é a aspa dupla, que deve ser usada duas caso queira adicionar uma no texto.

Answer (score 30):

Tenho dois complementos sobre o assunto.

## Palavra reservada

O `@` pode ser usado para outra coisa na linguagem. Quando você precisa usar um identificador que conflita com uma palavra reservada, este símbolo pode ser usado para indicar que ali é um identificador e resolver a ambiguidade. Exemplo:

```
var @lock = true;
```

Isto pode ser necessário para códigos legados e principalmente quando você usa uma biblioteca escrita em outra linguagem onde aquela palavra não é reservada.

## Nova forma de escapar uma *string*

Em C# 6 existe um novo símbolo para indicar uma condição especial daquela *string*. Com a adição de interpolação de *string*, poderemos usar a variável (e talvez uma expressão) dentro da *string*. Para isto o compilador precisa entender que isto está sendo usado nela. Seria assim:

```
var texto = $"Contei {x} vezes";
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Syntax/ReservedWordRawString.cs).

O `$` indica que o que o trecho com `{}` precisa ser resolvido em tempo de execução. Leia [mais sobre o assunto](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/91117/101).

Comment: Eu utilizo o `@` para concatenar texto em multiline, está correto isso?

Comment: @Marconi Precisaria ver a forma, mas me parece que sim, claro que isto não é exatamente concatenação, é só uma forma de escrever de forma apropriada :) A não ser que esteja concatenando mesmo, aí está errado :D

Comment: @Marconi parece adequado, eu só usaria também o `$` e colocaria as expressões dentro da *string*, mas é gosto: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/91117/101

Answer (score 2):

Para entender melhor a representação de strings em C#, eu sugiro a leitura dos artigos:

[String (Referência de C#)](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/string) e [String literals](http://String%20literals)

Resumidamente, o C# suporta dois tipos de representação de strings:

1. **string regular** que consiste numa sequência de caracteres entre aspas que podem conter combinações escape para representar caracteres especiais. As combinações escapes são inciadas com a barra invertida (\);
2. **string textual (verbatim)** que consiste numa sequência de caracteres entre aspas precedida do caractere @. As strings textuais não processam combinações escapes.

Exemplos:

```
string a = "Hello";           // string regular
string b = @"Hello";          // string textual
string c = "Hello \n World";  // string regular com o escape \n de quebra de linha
string d = @"Hello \n World"; // string textual não processa combinação escape

// strings textuais podem expandir por múltiplas linhas
string e = @"SELECT * 
FROM Funcionario 
WHERE nome LIKE '%Silva%'";
```

Answer (score 0):

É uma palavra reservada da linguagem, para escapar string.

```
   string arquivo = @"c:\arquivo.txt";
```