# Problemas com parâmetros no SqlCommand

Tags: c#, winforms, windows

Estou desenvolvendo um cadastro de serviços, a primeira tela é a de login e preciso pegar o cargo do usuário que logou e indicar um form pra ele, meu código ta assim:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Data.SqlClient;  

namespace PesadaoFinal
{
    public partial class frmLogin : Form
    {

        SqlConnection conn = null;
        private string conexao = @"Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\Breno\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\PesadaoFinal\PesadaoFinal\bd\pesadao_db.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30";
        private string consulta = string.Empty;

        public frmLogin()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        public void logar(){


            conn= new SqlConnection(conexao);

            try{
                string usuario, senha, cargo;

                usuario = txtUsu.Text;
                senha=txtSenha.Text;
                SqlDataReader verCargo = null;


                if(usuario==string.Empty && senha==string.Empty){

                    MessageBox.Show("Usuário e senha devem ser digitados!");
                }
                else if (usuario != null && senha != null)
                {
                    consulta = @"SELECT COUNT(cpf) FROM funcionarios WHERE login = @usuario AND senha = @senha";
                    SqlCommand novoLogin = new SqlCommand(consulta, conn);
                    novoLogin.Parameters.Add(@usuario, SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = usuario;
                    novoLogin.Parameters.Add(@senha, SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = senha;

                    conn.Open();


                    int rs = (int)novoLogin.ExecuteScalar();
                    if (rs > 0)
                    {
                        verCargo = novoLogin.ExecuteReader();
                        cargo = verCargo[7].ToString();
                        if (cargo == "funcionario")
                        {
                            formFunc novoForm = new formFunc();
                            this.Dispose();

                        } if (cargo == "diretor")
                        {
                            frmDiretor novoForm = new frmDiretor();
                            this.Dispose();

                        } if (cargo == "TI")
                        {
                            formTI novoForm = new formTI();
                            this.Dispose();


                        }
                        else
                        {
                            MessageBox.Show("Usuário ou Senha inválidos!");
                        }
                    }

                }


            }catch(SqlException erroBD){
                MessageBox.Show(erroBD +"Erro no banco");

            }


        }
        private void frmLogin_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {


        }

        private void btnLogar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            logar();
        }
    }
}
```

e a mensagem de erro que está dando é essa:

[image: imagem de erro ao rodar e tentar logar]

Comment: Você pode colocar na sua pergunta exemplos de código do que você tem até agora?

Comment: serão apenas dois tipos de form? eu não entendi muito bem, você poderia descrever como deve ser o resultado?

Comment: Cigano, apaguei todo meu código pra começar de novo, estava tendo muitos problemas. Jovita, seriam basicamente 3 tipos de forms, 1 que permitiria ao "diretor" cadastrar e excluir usuários e fazer todo resto, outro que seria pro funcionário cadastrar os serviços e outro pro "técnico", informar o caminho do banco, quando houvesse alguma mudança.

Comment: Reformulei minha pergunta e dei exemplos reais.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Provavelmente seu problema está aqui:

```
novoLogin.Parameters.Add(@usuario, SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = usuario;
novoLogin.Parameters.Add(@senha, SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = senha;
```

Você deve utilizar o as aspas duplas:

```
novoLogin.Parameters.Add("@usuario", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = usuario;
novoLogin.Parameters.Add("@senha", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = senha;
```

Da maneira que você tinha feito, você estava passando o **conteúdo** das variáveis `usuario` e `senha` como nomes dos parâmetros e não `@usuario` e `@senha` como você havia definido. Você pode entender um pouco mais do @ nessa pergunta [O que significa o sinal de arroba "@" no C#?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/41166).

Olhando a continuação do seu código, creio que você terá mais um problema

```
int rs = (int)novoLogin.ExecuteScalar();
if (rs > 0)
{
    verCargo = novoLogin.ExecuteReader();
    cargo = verCargo[7].ToString(); \\ <<--------- aqui
```

No *select* que você fez no `novoLogin` só possui uma coluna, e você tenta acessar a coluna 7, provavelmente você terá que ajustar o `CommandText` do `novoLogin` para que funcione.

Outro ponto seria o fato de você não estar exibindo o `Form` criado:

```
frmDiretor novoForm = new frmDiretor();
novoForm.Show(); // ou dependendo de como você fizer novoForm.ShowDialog();
this.Dispose();
```

Você poderia também utilizar `if` e alguns `else if` ao invés de só usar `if` para verificar os cargos.

Comment: Mateus, meu código agora na parte do ExecuteReader está assim, porém, não retorna nada e da erro.  object rs = novoLogin.ExecuteScalar();  
if (rs== null)  
{  
MessageBox.Show("Usuário ou Senha Incorretos");  
}  
else  
{  
verCargo = novoLogin.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection);  
if (verCargo != null)
{  
while (verCargo.Read())  

                            {  
usulogado=(verCargo[].ToString);  
cpf = (verCargo[].ToString);  
}  Já tentei passar verCargo[1], [2], por nome de coluna e nada vai.

Comment: @brenoguto, creio que nesse caso seria correto criar uma nova pergunta com esse problema específico, pois já é outra coisa e não mais o que você perguntou originalmente. Se considera que minha resposta te ajudou, você pode aceitá-la, caso não saiba como fazer isso você pode dar uma olhada no [tour]