# Qual é a diferença entre 'string' e r'string' em Python?

Tags: python, string

Estava dando uma olhada no código do Django, *framework* em Python, e me deparei com o seguinte código no arquivo `urls.py`.

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^articles/2003/$', views.special_case_2003),
    url(r'^articles/([0-9]{4})/$', views.year_archive),
    url(r'^articles/([0-9]{4})/([0-9]{2})/$', views.month_archive),
    url(r'^articles/([0-9]{4})/([0-9]{2})/([0-9]+)/$', views.article_detail),
]
```

Não compreendi de fato o que seria esse trecho

```
r'^articles/2003'
```

O que é esse `r` que antecede a declaração da *string*?

É algo relacionado à expressões regulares?

Comment: Sinceramente, não sei qual o problema tem a pergunta e por que recebeu -1

Comment: Não me importo, @gmsantos. Deixa isso para lá. Viva ao Stackoverflow Português!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Um melhor exemplo seria (o seu não faz diferença usar o `r`):

```
r'^articles\2003'
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Python/String/Raw.py).

Isto funciona do jeito que está. O `r` indica que a *string* é bruta, é assim mesmo e não considera caracteres especiais. Sem o `r` no literal a barra invertida (*backslash*) faria o que vem a seguir ser considerado um caractere especial. Então seria considerado um 200 em octal neste caso e depois o algarismo 3. O formato `\nnn` é um caractere representado em octal na *string* "normal". Obviamente todos aqueles caracteres de controle com o *backslash* são ignorados também.

Como logo você vai perguntar, `u` também pode ser usado para representar *strings* em codificação Unicode.

As aspas duplas não muda nada, ao contrário do PHP. Mas as aspas em triplicata """texto""" tem diferença, isto é [outro assunto](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/80551/101).

Comment: Mas isso não seria feito simplesmente utilizando uma áspas-dupla ao invés da simples? Não é assim no Python?

Comment: Cara, interessante! Será que caberia outra pergunta?! Porque parece não haver diferença entre `'` e `"` no python!

Comment: É isto, não há diferença, é gosto usar um ou outro em Python.

Comment: A falha da CloudFlare tá muito chata!!!!!, atrapalha nas piores horas!

Answer (score 10):

> O que é esse r que antecede a declaração da string?

O `r` antes das aspas vem de *raw*, ou seja, a string será interpretada como [uma string literal](https://docs.python.org/3.3/reference/lexical_analysis.html?highlight=string%20literals#string-and-bytes-literals).

Em uma string comum, temos a `\` como caracter de escape para representar quebras de linha (como `\n`, `\r`, `\t`) e outros. Em uma string literal, esses elementos não são processados.

```
# No primeiro caso, o trecho \123 será exibido ao invés de ser convertido
# para a representação octal da letra S
raw = r"\directory\123"
val = "\directory\123"

print(raw)
print(val)
```

Saída:

> \directory\123
>
> \directoryS

O comportamento é similar as [aspas simples do PHP](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/4652/diferen%C3%A7a-entre-aspas-simples-e-duplas-em-php) e o [`@` no C#](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/41167/4751).

---

> É algo relacionado à expressões regulares?

Não é relacionado diretamente, porém expressões regulares utilizam `\` para grupos de caracteres, como `\d` para representar dígitos de 0 a 9, `\s` para espaços em branco entre outros.

Como esses grupos podem conflitar com o caracter de escape, é preferível utilizar strings literais ao trabalhar com regex e não ter nenhuma surpresa com um match indesejado.

Comment: Vixi, agora me confudiu. Então qual seria a diferença entre `"string"`,  `r"string", `'string'` e `'r'string'`?

Comment: Aparentemente não tem diferença nenhuma `'` e `"` no pyhton - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/56011/single-quotes-vs-double-quotes-in-python

Comment: Agora está mais que entendido. Interessante é que não tem nada a ver com `regexp`. Achei que o `r` era de `regexp`

Comment: @WallaceMaxters editei a resposta. Tinha me esquecido da segunda questão.