# Como escrever múltiplas linhas em Python?

Tags: python, string

Como posso escrever uma `string` com múltiplas linhas em Python?

Como venho do PHP, eu costumo fazer assim:

```
$string = "
uma linha
outra linha2
"
```

Ou ainda:

```
$string = <<<EOT
uma linha
outra linha
EOT;
```

Quando tento fazer isso no Python, gera um erro.

Exemplo:

```
string = '
uma linha
outra linha
'
```

Resultado:

> EOL while scanning string literal

Como posso fazer isso em Python?

Comment: De preferência, de maneira elegante, e não como se faz no javascript!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Aspas triplicadas:

```
print("""linha1
linha2
linha3
""")
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](http://ideone.com/jGi9ja). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/@maniero/TripleQuotepy). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Python/String/TripleQuote.py).

Você pode usar aspas simples também, desde que estejam triplicadas.

Mas não pode usar indentação sob pena dela fazer parte da *string*.

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](http://ideone.com/ZlHTe2). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/@maniero/TripleQuote2py). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Python/String/TripleQuote2.py).

Isto também pode ser usado como [*doc strings*](https://docs.python.org/3.5/tutorial/controlflow.html#documentation-strings). Que nada mais são que *strings* soltas no código. Elas não serão atribuídas à variáveis nem serão impressas, só farão parte do código e isto indica que é um comentário de documentação que depois poderá ser lido por alguma ferramenta específica.

Comment: Não seria **Aspas triplas**?

Comment: Mas aí me surge a dúvida: Isso não é usado para documentar funções e para comentários?

Comment: Sim, melhorei esta parte. Tá difícil postar qualquer coisa com rapidez. É sacanagem a SE deixar ter usuários de primeira classe e outros de segunda. Aspas triplas não existem. Embora alguns chama isto desta forma.

Answer (score 5):

Para fazer uma string possui várias linhas pode-se usar o caractere de quebra de linha `\n`. Assim:

```
string = 'uma linha\noutra linha'
print string
```

Você pode ainda usar a função `os.linesep` que de acordo com a documentação ela faz uso do caractere de quebra de linha mais apropriado para seu sistema operacional, no caso do Windows seria o `\r\n`.

```
string = 'uma linha%soutra linha' % os.linesep
print string
```

Resultado para qualquer um dos dois casos acima:

> uma linha
>   outra linha

[Veja funcionando no Ideone](https://ideone.com/MP4iqo).

Referência: [Python Docs - linesep](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.linesep).

---

Caso o que você precise seja usar várias linhas para formar uma string com uma linha você pode fazer com `\`:

```
string = '\
uma linha \
outra linha\
'
print string
```

Ou com `()`:

```
string = ('uma linha '
'outra linha')
print string
```

Ou ainda com `()` e o `+`.

```
string = ('uma linha ' +
'outra linha')
print string
```

Resultado para qualquer um dos três casos acima:

> uma linha outra linha

[Veja funcionando no Ideone](https://ideone.com/S7SbVK).

Comment: Boa, @Math. Essa do `()` eu não sabia :)

Comment: A pergunta é uma string que inclua os caractéres de quebra de linha - a resposta via são as strings com aspas triplas.

Comment: @jsbueno puxa.. vc está coberto de razão, só agora abri o exemplo do bigown e entendi isso. Vou ver se conserto ou apago minha resposta (se é que há conserto, mas acho que não). Obrigado por perceber isso e avisar.

Comment: sempre dá pra consertar a resposta. Você pode adicionar a forma com aspas triplas ao começo da resposta, e escrever: "há outras formas de continuar strings em Python, sem colocar o caractere de quebra de linha" - Só que preste atençao que sua resposta ainda não cobre todas as formas. A mais usada, por exemplo, é simplesmente abrir aspas simples na linha de baixo, sem usar o "+"  - isso concatena as strings no passo de compilação.

Comment: @jsbueno editei minha pergunta. Pus duas opções para formar um string com quebra de linha dentro dela e adicionei a sua sugestão de não usar o `+`, que é o que na verdade o que faz mais sentido.

Answer (score 1):

E caso queira imprimir os valores de variáveis nessas linhas, pode fazer assim:

Lembrando que estou utilizando o Python 3.5

```
nome = 'rafael'
idade = '21'
peso = '68'
altura = '1.70'

print (
'\nNome: ' + nome +
'\nIdade: ' + idade +
'\nPeso: ' + peso+
'\nAltura: ' + altura +
'\n'
)
```