# Qual é a diferença da declaração dessas strings em Python?

Tags: python, string

Existe alguma diferença entre uma string declarada com aspas simples `'`

```
a = 'Special cases aren\'t special enough to break the rules.'
```

e outra com aspas duplas `"`

```
b = "Special cases aren't special enough to break the rules."
```

ou até com múltiplas aspas duplas `"""`

```
c = """Special cases aren't special enough to break the rules."""
```

ou simples `'''`

```
d = '''Special cases aren't special enough to break the rules.'''
```

no Python? De forma prática, não parece ter diferença nenhuma nessas quatro expressões, [veja no Ideone](https://ideone.com/qpLSnY).

Existe diferença? Existem casos em que seria preferível alguma das opções? Por quê?

Comment: Essa é uma questão que tem [uma resposta no sto em ingles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56011/single-quotes-vs-double-quotes-in-python) e foi fechada por ser considerada "Não construtiva".

Comment: Se não descaracterizar sua dúvida, por quê não adiciona também à pergunta as strings definidas com três aspas simples e com três aspas duplas? Por exemplo: `a = """teste"""`

Comment: Votei para reabrir a pergunta pois julgo que a pergunta marcada como duplicata não responde, de fato, a pergunta corrente. Na pergunta citada é tratado a diferença entre *char* e *string* no Python e comentado que ambos definem uma *string*, mas nada é dito (nem faz parte do escopo daquela pergunta) sobre as diferenças entre todas as declarações de *string*.

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss também creio que não, +1 um voto para reabrir.

Comment: **Relacionado:** [Como escrever múltiplas linhas em Python?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/80551/3635)