# Existe alguma forma de comentar múltiplas linhas em Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Para comentar uma linha, usamos o `#`.

Gostaria de de saber se é possível comentar múltiplas linhas em Python 3.

Se sim, como devo fazer?

Comment: Se estiver usando o Sublime Text e quiser comentar múltiplas linhas, basta selecioná-las e apertar `CTRL` + `/`

Answer (score 15):

Assim como colocado na [PEP 257](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0257/) (<s>[That's PEP](https://youtu.be/dQcnnZasL6A)</s>), *strings* que são a primeira instrução em um módulo, classe ou função serão consideradas como *strings* especiais: as *docstrings*.

> *A docstring is a string literal that occurs as the first statement in a module, function, class, or method definition.*

As *docstrings* são utilizadas pelo próprio Python para documentação e ficam acessíveis através de seus objetos pelo campo `__doc__`.

Mais adiante afirma também que qualquer outra *string* em qualquer outro ponto do código será tratada como comentário e, portanto, ignorado pelo interpretador.

> *String literals occurring elsewhere in Python code may also act as documentation.*

Então, **muito cuidado!** Enquanto os comentários iniciados por `#` serão **sempre** comentários, aqueles iniciados por aspas, seja simples ou dupla, podem não ser comentários.

```
""" Isto NÃO É um comentário.

String com múltiplas linhas que será docstring do módulo.
"""

# Isso É um comentário

def hello():
    'Isso NÃO É um comentário'
    print('hello')  # Isso É um comentário
    'Isso É um comentário'
```

Você pode confirmar isso utilizando o módulo [`dis`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dis.htmlTh):

```
  4           0 LOAD_CONST               0 (' Isto NÃO É um comentário.\n\nString com múltiplas linhas que será docstring do módulo.\n')
              2 STORE_NAME               0 (__doc__)

  8           4 LOAD_CONST               1 (<code object hello at 0x7f340fc28270, file "<dis>", line 8>)
              6 LOAD_CONST               2 ('hello')
              8 MAKE_FUNCTION            0
             10 STORE_NAME               1 (hello)
             12 LOAD_CONST               3 (None)
             14 RETURN_VALUE
None
```

<sup>Veja funcionando no [Repl.it](https://repl.it/@acwoss/SmugElasticInstruction)</sup>

Perceba que a primeira coisa feita é armazenar a *string* com múltiplas linhas em `__doc__`, pois, como é a primeira instrução do módulo, será a *docstring* deste. O comentário com `#` foi completamente ignorado ao gerar os *opcodes* pelo interpretador. Perceba que as *strings* dentro da função foram consideradas dentro de outra análise, exibida ali como "code object hello". Se analisar apenas o código interno a função, teremos:

```
  2           0 LOAD_CONST               0 ('Isso NÃO É um comentário')
              2 STORE_NAME               0 (__doc__)

  3           4 LOAD_NAME                1 (print)
              6 LOAD_CONST               1 ('hello')
              8 CALL_FUNCTION            1
             10 POP_TOP

  4          12 LOAD_CONST               2 (None)
             14 RETURN_VALUE
None
```

<sup>Veja funcionando no [Repl.it](https://repl.it/@acwoss/WarlikePreviousGigahertz)</sup>

Onde, novamente a primeira *string* não será um comentário, pois será interpretada como *docstring* da função, enquanto as outras foram ignoradas.

Concluindo, você pode utilizar qualquer variação de *string* do Python como comentário, desde que esta não seja interpretada como uma *docstring*.

Answer (score 7):

Segue abaixo um exemplo:

```
'''
Isso e um comentario multilinhas em Python.
'''
```

Comment: Só um detalhe para esclarecer aos leitores. Isso na verdade é uma string multilinha, que por acaso não vai ser usada para nada da forma que foi declarada, por não ter sido usada em função tampouco atribuida a alguma variável. Esta postagem ajuda a entender: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/80551/70

Comment: Mais que isso, a primeira ocorrência no módulo é tratada como docstring. Mais detalhes em https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0257/

Answer (score 1):

No pycharm você pode configurar no settings>keymap, geralmente vem configurado como padrão Ctrl+shit+.

segue exemplo visual:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 0):

Utilize `""" comentário """` para comentar em múltiplas linhas.

Comment: Vale o comentário que fiz na outra resposta