# erro no caminho para conexão com banco

Tags: python, banco-de-dados, sqlite3

Estou tentando adicionar este caminho para a conexão com o banco, e ele me dá este erro:

```
File "C:/Users/gabri/PycharmProjects/allbd_s/conc.py", line 4
    path='C:\Usuario\gabri\SQLite\conx'
        ^ SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 2-3: truncated \UXXXXXXXX escape
Process finished with exit code 1*
```

O algoritmo é este:

```
import sqlite3

#caminho
path = 'C:\Usuario\gabri\SQLite\conx'

#criar bd
conn = sqlite3.connect(path+r'teste.db')
```

PS: o endereço do caminho esta correto.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O caminho parece estar correto, mas não está. A barra invertida é a sequência de escape dentro de uma *string*, então `\U` não são dois caracteres, mas apenas um.

Ou você escapa as barras invertidas

```
path = 'C:\\Usuario\\gabri\\SQLite\\conx'
```

Ou utiliza o prefixo `r`:

```
path = r'C:\Usuario\gabri\SQLite\conx'
```

Veja:

- [Qual é a diferença entre 'string' e r'string' em Python?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/80545/5878)