# Mover arquivos em Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, arquivo

Eu pesquisei, e vi pessoas fazendo assim:

```
import shutil
shutil.move("este-arquivo", "/tmp")
```

Então, fiz aqui no meu:

```
import shutil    
shutil.move("arq.txt", "C:\Users\danielly.garcia\Desktop\pasta")
```

Só que, aparece o seguinte erro:

> File "C:/Users/danielly.garcia/Desktop/teste/Teste 01.py", line 7
>       shutil.move("arq.txt", "C:\Users\danielly.garcia\Desktop\pasta")
>                             ^ SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 2-3: truncated
>   \UXXXXXXXX escape

Tentei com os tambem:

```
 import os os.rename("arq.txt",
 "C:\Users\danielly.garcia\Desktop\pasta");
```

Mas dá exatamente o mesmo erro!

Comment: Relacionada: [Qual é a diferença entre 'string' e r'string' em Python?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/80545/5878)

Comment: Há relação com a resposta marcada mas é algo meio que indireto, o problema que ela está tendo é justamente por conta do \U dentro de "C:\Users\..." que o Python está tentando escapar como um caractere unicode, quando na realidade não é.

Comment: A solução para o problema é simples, onde houver uma barra invertida você deve colocar duas delas, ou seja, onde está `C:\Users\danielly.garcia\Desktop\pasta` deve ficar 'C:\\Users\\danielly.garcia\\Desktop\\pasta' (ou se precisar de uma solução mais independente de sistema operacional use o `os.path.join()`)