# Para que serve o @ em uma view e controller?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, .net, razor

Eu programo em PHP e estou começando a aprender a programar em C# ASP.Net MVC, porém estou com algumas dúvidas:

1. Pra que serve o @ (arroba) tanto no *controller* quanto na *view* ?
2. Pra que serve essas chamadas `{ get; set; }` que o pessoal coloca no *model*?

   public int id { get; set; }
   public string name { get; set; }

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Pra que serve o @ (arroba) tanto no *controller* quanto na *view*?

Na *View*, indica ao motor Razor que o código a seguir deve ser interpretado pelo .NET. Pode ser usado numa linha:

```
@if (condicao) { ... }
```

Ou pode servir como abertura de um bloco:

```
@{
    var minhaVariavel = ...;
}
```

Em teoria, o motor Razor interpreta qualquer código .NET, mas os mais usados são C# e VB.NET.

Não recomendo muito usar a segunda porque lógica de negócio na *View* deve ser desencorajada, já que a *View* serve para a apresentação, e não para lógica. É importante saber que o recurso existe, mas que não deve ser usado como no PHP.

> Pra que serve essas chamadas `{ get; set; }` que o pessoal coloca no *model*?

São propriedades automáticas (*auto properties*). É uma maneira concisa de escrever o seguinte:

```
private int _id;
public int id { 
    get { return _id; }
    set { _id = value; } 
}
```

Como a definição de propriedades é muito usada, essa escrita mais enxuta economiza esforço do programador.

Answer (score 8):

Na *view* usando o mecanismo de renderização [Razor](http://www.asp.net/web-pages/overview/getting-started/introducing-razor-syntax-(c)?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397) ele indica que o que vem à seguir é um código C# e não HTML, e por isto ele precisará ser executado e o resultado desta execução é que será renderizado como parte do HTML. Veja toda [sintaxe do Razor](http://haacked.com/archive/2011/01/06/razor-syntax-quick-reference.aspx/). Use o mínimo necessário.

No *controller* é uma [forma de escape](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/41166/101).

O `public int id { get; set; }` é uma [propriedade automática](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/properties?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397). Isto significa que será criado um membro interno na classe para guardar o estado de `id` e haverá dois métodos para acessar seu conteúdo. Este métodos são chamado de *getter* e *setter*. Mas eles não são chamados como métodos, a sintaxe é que como se estivesse acessando uma variável. É o mesmo que:

```
private int _id;
public int id {
    get { 
      return _id; 
    }
    set {
      _id = value; 
    }
}
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Property/Internal.cs).

Existem [vantagens e desvantagens em optar por uma propriedade](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/15467/101). No *model* costuma ser bem vantajoso para indicar os membros que devem guardar estado.