# Qual é a diferença entre o uso de aspas simples e aspas duplas no C#?

Tags: c#, .net, string, sintaxe

No PHP, quando utilizamos aspas simples ou aspas duplas, ambas as formas tem como funcionalidade a declaração de uma *string*. Existe apenas uma [pequena diferença](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/4652/diferen%C3%A7a-entre-aspas-simples-e-duplas-em-php).

Estou agora iniciando um estudo com C#. Quando fui tentar declarar uma *string* com aspas simples, foi gerado um erro.

```
 [Table('ProductSuppliers')]
```

> Too many characters in character literal

No PHP não tinha problema em usar aspas simples em casos como o mostrado acima.

Já que está sendo apontado o erro, me faz pensar que as aspas simples não tem o propósito que eu estava pensando.

- Qual é a finalidade das Aspas Simples em C#?
- Qual é a diferença dela para as Aspas Duplas?
- Por que ocorreu o erro descrito acima quando eu tentei usar a declaração `'ProductSupplier'`?

Comment: **TL;DR;**: Aspas simples: `char`. Aspas duplas: cadeia de `chars` (`string`)

Comment: Esse -1 aí poderia ser explicado. Assim eu poderia melhorar os detalhes da pergunta, já que ela contem algum erro

Answer (score 13, accepted):

É diferente do PHP onde elas são quase intercambiáveis.

Aspas simples ou apóstrofe serve apenas para delimitar um único caractere (tipo `char` - parte de um UTF-16).

Aspas duplas servem para delimitar uma *string*, ou seja, uma coleção imutável de `chars` com formato específico.

O erro indica justamente que tem mais de um caractere. Como é um texto e não apenas um caractere basta colocar aspas duplas.

As *strings* podem ser definidas com alguns prefixos para facilitar certas operações:

- [O que significa o simbolo "$" antes de uma string?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/91117/101)
- [O que significa o sinal de arroba "@" no C#?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/41166/101)

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Conceptual.md).

Answer (score 11):

Diferentemente do PHP, no C#, elas representam dois tipos diferentes.

**Aspas simples** servem para delimitar um único carácter (tipo `char`).

**Aspas duplas** servem para delimitar uma `string` (que é uma coleção imutável de `chars`).

O erro, no seu caso, ocorre porque existe mais de um carácter entre as aspas simples. O que você pretende usar aí é uma *string*, então basta trocar as aspas simples por duplas.

Exemplo:

```
char meuChar = 'A';
char[] meuCharArray = { 'O', 'L', 'Á' };
string minhaString = "OLÁ";
```

---

Algumas outras linguagens também trabalham dessa forma.

Answer (score 9):

As aspas simples representam um char, logo devem ser usadas **UNICAMENTE** para atribuir caracteres. 
Ex:

```
char sexo = 'M';
```

As aspas duplas representam uma cadeia de caracteres ( uma coleção de char ). 
Ex:

```
string sexo = "masculino";
```

Note que uma String (Cadeia de caracteres, ou array de char ) pode conter apenas um caractere, mas um char **NUNCA** poderá conter mais que um caractere. Ex:

```
string sexo = "M"; // Correto, uma cadeia de caracteres pode conter apenas um caractere.
char sex = 'sexo'; // Erro de compilação, um char não pode conter mais que um caractere.
```