# Usando "String.Replace()" a string continua igual

Tags: c#, .net, string, replace

Eu tenho a seguinte *string*:

```
string tt= "{\"Response\":{\"StatusCode\":200,\"StatusMessage\":\"OK\",\"Content\":{\"family\":{\"codigo\":14,\"descricao\":\"Cal\\u00e7a\",\"frontoffice\":1,\"posicaofront\":31,\"posicaoprint\":26,\"fundo\":\"#c0c0c0\",\"letra\":\"#000000\",\"tipo\":0,\"loja\":14,\"subfamilies\":[{\"codigo\":60005,\"descricao\":\"Ganga\",\"familia\":14,\"fundo\":\"#c0c0c0\",\"letra\":\"#000000\",\"posicao\":0,\"loja\":\"14\",\"lastupdate\":\"2015-12-04 16:51:26\"}],\"lastupdate\":\"\",\"famzonas\":[{\"loja\":14,\"familia\":14,\"zona\":0}]}}}}";
```

E quanto eu tento dar `Replace()` no "\u00e7" a *string* fica igual:

```
tt.Replace("\u00e7", "c");
```

Depois de executar esse comando a saída continua a mesma:

```
{"Response":{"StatusCode":200,"StatusMessage":"OK","Content":{"family":{"codigo":14,"descricao":"Cal\u00e7a","frontoffice":1,"posicaofront":31,"posicaoprint":26,"fundo":"#c0c0c0","letra":"#000000","tipo":0,"loja":14,"subfamilies":[{"codigo":60005,"descricao":"Ganga","familia":14,"fundo":"#c0c0c0","letra":"#000000","posicao":0,"loja":"14","lastupdate":"2015-12-04 16:51:26"}],"lastupdate":"","famzonas":[{"loja":14,"familia":14,"zona":0}]}}}}
```

Como consigo mudar o "\u00e7" para o carácter "c"?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Simples:

```
tt = tt.Replace("\u00e7", "c");
```

Variáveis são [imutáveis](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/15510/101), então quando você usa o método, ele não altera a própria *string*, ele gera uma nova e retorna para você fazer o que desejar com ela. Você pode usar em outra expressão ou guardar em uma variável. Pode ser uma variável nova ou pode ser a mesma, assim o valor novo substitui o valor antigo. Por isso qualquer operação que mude algo em *string* que você possa evitar ou minimizar é vantajoso.

A [documentação](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.replace?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=net-5.0#System_String_Replace_System_String_System_String_) mostra isso.

Tem mais um problema. Por coincidência o trecho de texto que deseja trocar é um formato de caractere entrado de forma especial. O `\u` significa que o código a seguir é um código Unicode para o caractere desejado. Então há uma impedância na representação. Ele não enxerga esse conjunto de caracteres `u00e7`, ele enxerga como o `ç`. Também é fácil resolver isso. Use uma [*string* verbatim](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/41166/101) onde cada caractere é interpretado como está ali, ele ignora as representações especiais.

```
using static System.Console;
                    
public class Program {
    public static void Main() {
        var tt= "{\"Response\":{\"StatusCode\":200,\"StatusMessage\":\"OK\",\"Content\":{\"family\":{\"codigo\":14,\"descricao\":\"Cal\\u00e7a\",\"frontoffice\":1,\"posicaofront\":31,\"posicaoprint\":26,\"fundo\":\"#c0c0c0\",\"letra\":\"#000000\",\"tipo\":0,\"loja\":14,\"subfamilies\":[{\"codigo\":60005,\"descricao\":\"Ganga\",\"familia\":14,\"fundo\":\"#c0c0c0\",\"letra\":\"#000000\",\"posicao\":0,\"loja\":\"14\",\"lastupdate\":\"2015-12-04 16:51:26\"}],\"lastupdate\":\"\",\"famzonas\":[{\"loja\":14,\"familia\":14,\"zona\":0}]}}}}";
        tt = tt.Replace(@"\u00e7", "c");
        WriteLine(tt);
    }
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/G5U7vc). E [no **.NET Fiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/bMoN9k). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/bigown/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/String/SaveReplace.cs).

Comment: Entendi o que estava a fazer de mal, quanto ao segundo problema antes de ter visto o seu edit eu tinha posto o código da seguinte maneira e funcionou

 <code>tt = tt.Replace("\\u00e7", "c");  </code>

Comment: @Medium estranho, não era para funcionar não, veja: https://dotnetfiddle.net/Q8rvS5

Comment: ♦ o código que eu tinha comentado estava mal já editei e foi assim que funcionou usado as "\\" antes do "u00e7"

Comment: @Medium verdade, eu não tinha me atentado que você usou o `\\` que também resolve.

Answer (score 2):

SOLUÇÃO SIMPLES

Use o `@`

```
tt = tt.Replace(@"\u00e7", "c");
```