# Converter caminho C:\\ para C:\

Tags: c#, string, path

Estou tentando pegar o caminho que esta guardado no banco e abrir pelo explorer, e para isso utilizei o código abaixo

```
path = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(configuracaoBackupAtual.LocalPadraoBackupSqlServer);
                string argument = @"/select, " + path;
                System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("explorer.exe", argument);
```

Porém o caminho do path fica `C:\\Program Files\\Microsoft SQL Server\\MSSQL12.SQLEXPRESS2016\\MSSQL`

Quando publico não apareceu as duas barras invertidas no nome. Acredito que seja por isso que não abre a pasta que eu quero.

Outra coisa que fiquei em dúvida é porquê colocar `@` antes pegar um caminho `string abc = @"c:\"`.

Comment: Não entendi bem a dúvida, e acho que não precisa de nada do que está dizendo aí, a não ser que a dúvida seja outra. Seria interessante mostrar o que tem em `configuracaoBackupAtual.LocalPadraoBackupSqlServer`. Manda imprimir o conteúdo para ver se está do jeito que precisa antes de chamar alguma coisa. Também pode usar o *debug*. Quando você encontra uma porta na frente, você usa a maçaneta para abrir a porta, não adianta ficar empurrando ela. Pode ler isto: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/41166/101. Se for só isto, é duplicata.

Comment: O @ tenque ser colocado porque \ é um caractére especial. Se remover ele, tenque ser usado "\\" ao invéz de "\". Aqui diz mais: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/41166/o-que-significa-o-sinal-de-arroba-no-c?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: beleza, obrigado pelas informações, vou seguir o procedimento...

Comment: Mas você não precisaria botar o `@` em "/select" já que a barra do select é uma barra não invertida.