# Replace com \ não funciona

Tags: c#, .net, string, replace

Estou tentando fazer um `Replace()` porém ele não funciona. Preciso trocar de `\` para `\\`.

```
"\r\n".Replace(@"\", "\\");
```

ele só me retorna : `"\r\n"` e não `"\\r\\n"`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Primeiro, acho que não precisa fazer isto, mas estou só especulando. Acho que tem outro problema está dando uma solução errada.

Não está dando certo porque está mudando uma coisa por ela mesma. `@"\"` é exatamente a mesma coisa que `"\\"`.

Assim funciona:

```
var texto = @"\r\n".Replace(@"\", @"\\");
```

O [`@`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/41166/101) faz com que o caractere de escape `\` seja considerado um caractere normal, entre outras coisas. Quando usa `\\` sem o `@` a barra invertida é um escape e quando usa duas barras invertidas significa que deve considerar a barra como caractere normal.

Não esqueça de guardar a informação em algum lugar (como eu fiz) ou usar imediatamente na expressão.

```
using static System.Console;

public class Program {
    public static void Main() {
        var texto = @"É necessário Cadastrar o(s) seguinte(s) Parâmetro(s):SENHA_FTP\r\n";
        WriteLine(texto.Replace(@"\", @"\\"));
    }
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/9MWRhY). E [no **.NET Fiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/ZJEJOk). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/String/Escape.cs).

Comment: não deu certo...

Comment: Tinha esquecido um `@`, agora sim.

Comment: Funcionou o seu exemplo, porem com o meu não... texto="É necessário Cadastrar o(s) seguinte(s) Parâmetro(s):SENHA_FTP\r\n"   texto = @texto.Replace(@"\", @"\\");

Comment: Funcionou o seu exemplo, eu fiz o que você colocou na pergunta. Se o que você queria fazer era outra coisa, deveria ter colocado na pergunta o que queria.