# c# - Erro ao tentar fazer o Replace de uma string

Tags: c#, html, string

Boas Pessoal,

Estou com o seguinte problema:

Ao tentar fazer o `replace` de uma string (de um `Literal Control`), utilizando o código a seguir apresentado, o valor da mesma não é alterado.

```
 MyControl.Text.Replace("id=\"KP\"", "id=\"KPC\"");
```

No entanto, se eu tentar alterar só o value do `id` (como mostra o código seguinte), funciona na perfeição.

```
 MyControl.Text.Replace("KP", "KPC");
```

P.S: tenho que utilizar o id no replace, porque o texto do `literal` contêm mais do que uma vez a referência ao valor do `id`.

[EDIT] - Deixo aqui um excerto do `literal` para melhor compreensão (é repetitivo)

```
<li><a class="fancybox" title="BK-001" href="imgpeles/KP-01.jpg" rel="fancybox">
    <img alt="" src="imgpeles/KP-01_t.jpg" width="55" height="55" id="KP-01"><br>
    BK-001</a>
</li>
```

Comment: Criei um pequeno exemplo e tudo funcionou corretamente, não percebo o porquê de não lhe estar a funcionar. Colocou o código assim, correto? `MyControl.Text = MyControl.Text.Replace("id=\"KP\"", "id=\"KPC\"");`

Comment: @JoãoMartins exatamente assim, não consigo perceber o erro...

Comment: @JoãoMartins fiz uma edição e pus um excerto do `literal`

Comment: Acho que ele não está a "gostar" da "\" no texto. Experimente assim: `MyControl.Text.Replace(@"id=""KP""", @"id=""KPC""");`

Comment: @JoãoMartins eu acho que já experimentei todas as possibilidades menos aquela que será a solução xD, já experimentei essa também e nada (apesar de ser uma boa proposta). Eu, também, já cheguei à conclusão que a "\" será o problema, mas como não a posso remover  (dado corresponder a um caminho), não sei muito bem por onde me guiar.

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Replace com \ não funciona](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/260390/replace-com-n%c3%a3o-funciona)

Comment: @ramaral não acho que seja duplicado, até porque o código `MyControl.Text.Replace(@"id=""KP""", @"id=""KPC""");` também não funciona. Há aqui algo que não bate certo...

Comment: @ramaral, posso estar enganado, mas eu acho que não é duplicado, até porque se eu substituir a barra por duas, ele também vai substituir as dos elementos (`a` e `li`)

Comment: @AdrianoMaia tem a certeza que o texto `id=\"KP\"` existe exatamente dessa forma no `MyControl.Text`?

Comment: @JoãoMartins sim, também já verifiquei isso no Debug

Comment: Pelo que entendi você está tentando dar replace em (id="KP-01"), mas o seu código considera (id="KP"). Creio que esse pode ser o erro.

Comment: @FilipeAndréFloriani, não xD. Eu só quero substituir a parte `KP` por `KPC`

Comment: Então tire a última "

Comment: Vou simular aqui e se der certo posto como resposta

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Segue abaixo solução:

```
string teste = System.IO.File.ReadAllText("c:\\arquivo.txt");          

teste = teste.Replace("id=\"KP", "id=\"KPC");
```

Observação: O arquivo `.txt` continha seu HTML.

Comment: é isso mesmo. Muito obrigado :).

Comment: Que bom que foi resolvido! :]