# Qual a diferença entre criar uma string com aspas e com colchetes?

Tags: string, lua

Sempre criei as *strings* com as aspas, dessa forma:

```
local minhaString = "Eu sou uma string"
```

Baixei um *source* para dar uma estudada na linguagem e me deparei com a seguinte forma de criar uma *string*:

```
local query = [[
SELECT *
FROM `pointshop_data`
WHERE uniqueid = '%s'
]]
```

Qual a vantagem/diferença em usar o `[[ / ]]`? Como eu passo o parâmetro `%s`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A forma com colchetes é mais bruta, ela essencialmente não trabalha com caracteres especiais e considera "tudo" como texto, incluindo quando pula a linha. É como usar o [`@` do C#](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/41166/101).

Para usar argumentos para serem inseridos no texto deve usar a função [`string.format()`](https://www.lua.org/pil/20.html).

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Lua/Conceptual.md).

Answer (score 2):

A principal diferença é que strings criados com aspas aceitam sequências de escape como `\n` e `\t`. Strings criados com colchetes não interpretam nenhuma sequência de escape.
Veja o [manual](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.2/pt/manual.html#3.1).

O `%s` no seu exemplo indica que provavelmente o string vai ser usado como formato em `string.format`. Fora isso, não há nenhum significado especial.