# Como usar aspas C#?

Tags: c#, string, sintaxe

Estou começando a programar em C# e estou sentindo algumas dificuldades com as aspas quando preciso colar algum texto. No Python eu podia usar as aspas triplas para colar algum texto que houvesse quebra de linha, já no C# não tenho ideia de como fazer isso e acabo tendo que fazer manualmente com `\n`

#### Exemplo Python:

```
print('''Olá!
Como você está?''')
```

Comment: Se puder postar um exemplo de código, ajudaria a entender a situação. Mas já adiantando, tenta usar a propriedade `Environment.NewLine`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A solução que é equivalente às aspas triplas de Python é o `@`. É possível fazer de outras formas, mas elas não são equivalentes. Só o `@`, chamado de [*string verbatim*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/41166/101) tem os mesmos benefícios e compromissos que obtém com Python.

A concatenação em alguns casos pode ter otimização e acabar dando no mesmo, mas não conte que ocorrerá sempre igual. O `StringBuilder` é para outro tipo de necessidade.

Faça assim:

```
WriteLine(@"Olá!
Como você está?");
```

Nos casos que precise colocar algo dentro dela pode usar a [interpolação](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/91117/101):

```
using static System.Console;

public class Program {
    public static void Main() {
        var nome = "João";
        WriteLine(@"Olá!
Como você está?");
        WriteLine($@"Olá {nome}!
Como você está?");
    }
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/HzVvtT). E [no **.NET Fiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/s4OoGJ). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/String/Verbatim.cs).

Comment: Eu uso muito com `$`, facilita demais com variáveis, do que ficar colocar muitos `+`.

Answer (score 4):

Aí vai algumas formas:

```
public static void Main()
{
    Console.WriteLine(@"Olá 1!
Como você está?");

    Console.WriteLine("Olá 2!\n"+"Como você está?");

    Console.WriteLine("Olá 3! {0}Como você está ?",
                      Environment.NewLine);
}
```

Saída:

```
//Olá 1!
//Como você está?
//Olá 2!
//Como você está?
//Olá 3! 
//Como você está ?
```